# How to delete relationships in Neo4j using python neo4j-rest-client library?

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, neo4jrestclient

I am not able to find the API to delete relationships from a Node, I could only find a create method. Please let me know how I can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly about the python library but my understanding is that it mimics the Java API.

In Java API you'd use:

```
for (Relationship r: myNode.getRelationships()) {
    r.delete();
}
```

I guess the same concept is valid for python's neo4jrestclient as well: get all relationships of a node and call the `delete()` method on them.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right:

```
rel = n1.relationships.create("Knows", n2)
rel.delete()
```

And that's it.